# IsEmpty is not working as expected

Tags: vbscript

I have written a VBScript to group the files based on the file type for a particular folder path (given as input).  I'm trying to handle a scenario that when a folder path is empty, the script should ask us to mention the file path.  However, I'm not able to handle it.

```
v_Path = InputBox("Enter the FileName Along With Path")
If IsEmpty(v_Path) Then
    MsgBox("What's the File Path?")
Else
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(v_Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile in colFiles   
        v_FileName = v_Path&"\" & objFile.Name
        v_FileExtensionName = v_Path & "\" & objFso.GetExtensionName(v_FileName)
        If Not(objFso.FolderExists(v_FileExtensionName)) Then
            objFso.CreateFolder(v_FileExtensionName)
            objFso.MoveFile v_FileName, v_FileExtensionName & "\"
        Else
            objFso.MoveFile v_FileName, v_FileExtensionName & "\"
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox("Files Grouped Based on File Type!!")
End If
Set objFso = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set colFiles = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IsEmpty is looking at the string here and saying v_Path is initiliazed or not.  If the variable was an object reference, or not declared, then isEmpty will return true.  In this case, the message box returns an empty string or ""

Try this change,

```
If Isempty(v_Path) or v_Path = "" Then
```

or just

```
If v_Path = "" Then
```